# Issue with webm video format playback in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, html5-video, webm

Using VideoJS I'm having issues with the webm format failing to play back in Firefox.

After researching this issue here I made the appropriate changes to my htaccess file. That fixed ogg and ogv playback, but not webm. I've tested the webm video file itself and it plays back fine in VLC player.

The mp4 format and flahs formats work great. Thanks in advance for any ideas on this.

htaccess:

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .web
```

HTML excerpt:

```
<video id="abacus_holiday_video" class="video-js vjs-holiday-skin" loop autoplay controls
  preload="auto" width="640" height="390" poster="my_video_poster.png"
  data-setup="{  }">
  <source src="abacus_holiday.webm" type='video/webm'>
  <source src="abacus_holiday.mp4" type='video/mp4'>

</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess maps extensions to mime types. Your extension in the code i.e. on the end of the src attribute is .webm but your mime type mapping is .web so there is no match.

Either change/add a mapping in htaccess for webm i.e.

```
AddType video/webm .webm
```

or rename the file to .web.

The former seems best FWIW.